# Make Node/MEANjs Highly Available

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I'm probably opening up a can of worms with regard to how many hundreds of directions can be taken with this- but I want high availability / disaster recovery with my MEANjs servers.

Right now, I have 3 servers:

- MongoDB
- App (Grunt'ing the main application, this is the front end
  server)
- A third server for other processing on the back-end

So at the moment, if I reboot my MongoDB server (or more realistically, it crashes for some reason), I suddenly see this in my App server terminal:

> MongoDB connection error: Error: failed to connect to
>   [172.30.3.30:27017] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes
>   before starting...

After MongoDB is back online, nothing happens on the app server until I re-grunt.

What's the best practice for this situation? You can see in the error I'm using nodeMon to monitor changes to the app. I bet upon init I could get my MongoDB server to update a file on the app server within nodemon's view to force a restart? Or is there some other tool I can use for this? Or should I be handling my connections to the db server more gracefully so the app doesn't "crash"?

Is there a way to re-direct to a secondary mongodb in case the primary isn't available? This would be more apt to HA/DR type stuff.

Comment: That _heavily_ depends on what kind of HA you want to achieve. Within you DC? Multi-DC? Country? Globally? What is your budget? With the question as is, one could write books about it.

Comment: So this is why it's a can of worms. I understand it can be done a million ways (as is typical not just of HA, but the nature of the open web community). Let's keep it simple for now: low budget, using AWS (I know, this opens up another set of possible avenues), not relevant to region-based HA. To clarify: options for minimum viable product for MEANjs database failover. I mean it could simply be something like.. don't point your app directly to MongoDB, instead point it to a "database picker server" that responds with the IP (or performs CRUD) of an available DB. Just looking for best practices

Comment: Uhm, you are aware that MongoDB comes with its own [failover capabilities called "replica sets"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/)? I'll come up with sth.

Comment: side note: I use nodemon in development environments. For Production, I have seen [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) used instead of nodemon

Answer (score 2):

I would like to start with a side note: Given the description in the question and the comments to it, I am not convinced that using AWS is a wise option. A PaaS provider like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com), [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com) or [AppFog](http://appfog.com) seems to be more suitable, especially when combined with a MongoDB service provider. Running MongoDB on EBS can be quite a challenge when you are new to MongoDB. And pretty expensive, too, as soon as you need provisioned IOPS.

> **Note** In the following paragraphs, I simplified a few things for the sake of comprehensibility

If you insist on running it on your own, however, you have an option. MongoDB itself comes with means of automatic, transparent failover, called [a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/).

A minimal replica set consists of of two data bearing nodes and a so called arbiter. Write operations go to the node currently elected *"primary"* only, and reads do, too, unless you explicitly allow or request reads to be performed on the current *"secondary"*. The secondary constantly syncs to the primary. If the current primary goes down for some reason, the former secondary becomes elected primary.

The arbiter is there so that there is always a quorum (qualified majority would be an equivalent term) of members to elect the current secondary to be the new primary. This quorum is mainly important for edge cases, but since you can not rule out these edge cases, an uneven number of members is a hard requirement for a MongoDB replica set (setting aside some special cases).

The beauty of this is that almost all drivers, and the node.js for sure, are replica set aware and deal with the failover procedure pretty gracefully. They simply send the reads and writes to the new primary, without any change to be done at any other point.

You only need to deal with some cases during the failover process. Without going into much detail, you basically check for certain errors in the according callbacks and redo the operation, if you encounter one of those errors and redoing the operation is feasible.

As you might have noticed, the third member, the arbiter, does not hold much data. It is a very lightweight process and can basically run on the cheapest instance you can find.

So you have data replication and automatic, transparent failover with relative ease at the cost of the cheapest VM you can find, since you would need two data bearing nodes anyway if you used any other means.